# When Using getFunctions from firebase-admin/functions: Error: Unexpected annotation generated by the Firebase Functions SDK. This should never happen

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have the following cloud functions in my index.ts file, one of which creates the task queue functions and the other of which enqueues functions.

```
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as fs from "fs";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase-admin/functions";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);


export const retireAtlistedEvents = functions
    .runWith( { memory: '2GB' })
    .tasks.taskQueue({
      retryConfig: {
        maxAttempts: 5,
        minBackoffSeconds: 60,
      },
      rateLimits: {
        maxConcurrentDispatches: 6,
      },
    }).onDispatch(async (data) => {
      const minEvent = data.minEvent as MinEventInfo;
     })

    export const enqueueAtlistedEventsToRetire = functions
    .runWith( { memory: '2GB' })
    .pubsub
    .schedule('0,15,30,45 * * * *').onRun(async context => {
        const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue("retireAtlistedEvents");
  
        const enqueues = [];

        let minEvent: MinEventInfo = {
          proId: "abcd",
          eventId: "efgh"
        }

        enqueues.push(
          queue.enqueue({minEvent: minEvent}, {
              dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 20 // 20 seconds
          }),
        );

        await Promise.all(enqueues)
          .then(() => {
            const exit: ExtendedExitMessage = {
              exit: 0,
              message: "enqueueAtlistedEventsToRetire success",
              success: true,
            };
            return exit;
          })
          .catch(() => {
            const exit: ExtendedExitMessage = {
              exit: 1,
              message: "enqueueAtlistedEventsToRetire success",
              success: false,
            };
            return exit;
          });
      });
```

When running:

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:retireAtlistedEvents,functions:enqueueAtlistedEventsToRetire"
```

I get:

```
=== Deploying to 'my-project'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Unexpected annotation generated by the Firebase Functions SDK. This should never happen.
```

My suspicion is that this line is causing this:

const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue("retireAtlistedEvents");

as right before trying to deploy these functions, I was able to deploy another function without this code. Is something possibly wrong with the way I am importing getFunctions?

Comment: Further info: my firebase-tools version is 9.16.6

Comment: Version 9.16.6 was released on Aug 25, 2021. The current version is 11.16.1. Is there a reason you did not install that latest version?

Comment: There is no particular reason that I can't upgrade to 11.16.1... would you recommend trying that?

Comment: The error message indicates features that the version you are using does not support.

Comment: Well I upgraded to 11.16.1 and now it is complaining about @babel/core here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74671138/when-deploying-firebase-cloud-functions-i-get-build-failed-npm-err-cannot-rea , trying to avoid this dependency hell is honestly why I didn't want to upgrade.